# Doctrine AnnotationReader doesn't work for relation entity

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, doctrine, reader

In my Symfony 5 project (PHP 8), I have set up a custom annotation called Uploadable.

Here is how I check that the **@Uploadable** annotation is present on an entity:

```php
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;

class UploadAnnotationReader
{
    private AnnotationReader $reader;

    public function __construct(private EntityManagerInterface $manager){
        $this->reader = new AnnotationReader();
    }

    /**
     * @throws \ReflectionException
     */
    public function isUploadable($entity):bool
    {
        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass(get_class($entity));

        return $this->reader->getClassAnnotation($reflection, Uploadable::class) !== null;
    }
```

When I pass in parameter an entity (which does have the annotation that I created) obtained either directly from the database, or from the Symfony paramConverter, then the AnnotationReader is able to see this annotation.

On the other hand, if I get this entity back through a relation from another entity, oddly, it won't work anymore!

```php
$entityA = $manager->getRepository(...)....;
$myService->isUploadable($entityA); // return true
```

```php
$entityB = $manager->getRepository(...)....;
$myService->isUploadable($entityB->getEntityA()); // return false
```

```php
$entityB = $manager->getRepository(...)....;
$entityA = $entityB->getEntityA();

$myService->isUploadable($entityB->getEntityA()); // return true
```

And I don't know why...

Comment: Could you add the code of your Uploadable annotation?

Comment: I finally found the solution, we have to use the Doctrine Utils class

Comment: Cool! answer your own question to share the result with us :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Juste use the **Doctrine\Common\Util\ClassUtils::getClass** instead of php native function '**get_class**'